# Include fields with custom annotation with JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.hasIgnoreMarker()

Tags: java, jackson

I want to include only fields in my classes that have my custom annotation `@MyInclude` but Jackson ends up ignoring everything. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreIntrospector());

    MyNestedObject nestedObject = new MyNestedObject("value1", "value2");

    MyObject object = new MyObject();
    object.setNestedObject(nestedObject);

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object); //This returns {}
  }

  public static class IgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3951086067314107368L;

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
      return !m.hasAnnotation(MyInclude.class) || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
    }
  }


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyObject {
  @MyInclude
  private MyNestedObject nestedObject;
}

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyNestedObject {
  @MyInclude
  private String value1;
  private String value2;
}
```

`mapper.writeValueAsString(object)` is returning `{}` but it should return `NestedObject` with value1 populated instead (ignoring value2).

If I update my `IgnoreIntrospector.hasIgnoreMarker ()` to just `super.hasIgnoreMarker(m)` then everything would be included in the json string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IgnoreIntrospector` alone wasn't enough. Since my custom annotations were only on fields, I needed to disable all visibility:

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreIntrospector());

mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
.withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
.withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
.withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
.withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
.withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

And updated my `IgnoreIntrospector`:

```
 public static class IgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
      return m instanceof AnnotatedField && _findAnnotation(m, MyInclude.class) == null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, override both `hasIgnoreMarker()` and `findNameForSerialization()`:

```
JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                                  .annotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()
                                  {
                                      @Override
                                      public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m)
                                      {
                                          return m.hasAnnotation(CustomIgnore.class) || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
                                      }

                                      @Override
                                      public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a)
                                      {
                                          if(a.hasAnnotation(CustomIgnore.class)) return null;
                                          return super.findNameForSerialization(a);
                                      }
                                  })
                                  .build();
```